# how should I publicly announce a new ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I just made my first ruby gem and pushed it to rubygems.org.

I'd like to make its existence known to anyone who might be interested, for testing and feedback.

What's the best, most canonical way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a thread in the official ruby forums, also forums/blogs that post about Ruby, and any website that's related to the gem you made.

Honestly I don't think you need to advertise the gem much, usually when I want to search for a gem I just put whatever I want to look for in the search bar, so make sure your gem shows up if people do it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @T.Aoukar already suggested, you can also try `#rubyonrails` on `irc.freenode.net`, and any Ruby mailing lists that might be relevant. Make sure you check their policy first, but it should be fine.

Another good way to promote your Gem is to give a talk at your local or regional Ruby meet up, (I really hope there is one in your area. If not, maybe you can start one?), and on the community Slack channel, or similar.

A lot of Rubyists are also very active on social networks like Twitter. That gives you another channel to look for feedback and promotion.